# Reading stdout of nodejs from Java (using apache commons exec). Thread safe or not?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to write a torrent streaming client in Java using webtorrent-cli, which runs on NodeJS. When installed as a node module, webtorrent-cli gives a nice `webtorrent.cmd` script which can be used to work with it. When download for a torrent starts, the cli updates the standard output each second with useful details like download speed, % of torrent downloaded, seeds available etc.

To observe such a "dynamic" stdout in Java (with commons exec), I am using the following snippet:

```
private static Thread processCreator() {
    return new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            // Read stdout in a thread safe manner (hopefully)
            final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PumpStreamHandler handler = new PumpStreamHandler(baos);

            String command = getCommand();
            CommandLine cmd = CommandLine.parse(command);

            Executor cmdExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
            cmdExecutor.setStreamHandler(handler);

            // Schedule a service to print the content of baos each second
            final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                try {
                    // Read and reset atomically
                    synchronized (baos) {
                        System.out.println(baos.toString("UTF-8"));

                        // Resetting so that buffer size doesn't grow arbitrarily
                        baos.reset();
                    }
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            cmdExecutor.execute(cmd);

            // Let the remaining bytes be processed
            sleep(1000);

            // Shutdown
            service.shutdown();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread process = processCreator();
    process.start();
    process.join();
}
```

I'm concerned about how the `ByteArrayOutputStream` is being written. The class itself is thread safe, but if the implementation writes to the buffer byte by byte, or in a way that "updated output" (from webtorrent-cli) is only partially written to the buffer by the time scheduled service captures the monitor and starts processing, then that's going to cause problems. In this case, because I'm just printing content of the buffer, it won't be that much of trouble I guess. But I've to process the output and extract out a couple of details in the fixed scheduled service. I can think of a different way to achieve proper co-ordination (e.g.: observe the completeness of an update by marking the event when buffer receives bytes that form the first line in webtorrent-cli's stdout...and mark the update as completed when buffer receives bytes that form the last line. Each update has identical first and last lines...or at least a few bytes in the beginning and end are identical). But that would be a bit more work than this. My question is, can I be certain that write to the buffer has happened in a single atomic call to `ByteArrayOutputStream.write(byte[], ...)`'. I hope I've explained my question well enough. If you need more details, let me know in the comments. BTW, when the code above is run, the output suggests that co-ordination is being properly managed. But maybe I'm just lucky that the race condition has been avoided so far?

Comment: Wound up everytime I tried to look up the code that writes to the buffer in my IDE's decompiler. I have run the app a 100 times now and since I did not find an answer on StackOverflow, I'm going to assume that the bytes are all written at once.